# Can a fencepost under a deck double as a (quasi)support beam?

Tags: fence, post

(Another entry in my series of questions on the [world's slowest fencing project](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/241926/dealing-with-remnants-of-old-fence-post).)

I ended up with a bit of an awkward angle from a fence gate post next to a concrete slab to the house. So my solution was to use concrete anchors to attach a 4x4 to my slab (in a straight line from the gate post), and the I have a nice 90° angle from the 4x4 back to the house. Pictures below:

[image]

[image]

Now since I already had some 4x4 posts on this same slab acting as braces for the deck overhead (see the second picture, background), I figured I'd do the same with this one, paint it like the others, but also use it as a fencepost to make the strecth from that gate post to the house.

Here's the question: I've since read/remembered that its a Bad Idea to attach a fence directly to the house, as they are apt to move separately over time. I'm of course not going to nail cross-beams from that 4x4 to the siding, but I'm wondering if this 4x4 being attached to that top bean under the 2nd story deck counts, and if that is also a Bad Idea? Should I instead just trim the 4x4 to the height of the other gate post, and just use it like a post (but attached to the slab)? Was even attaching it to the slab a bad idea?

Comment: Usually never a good idea to use a support post for a fence.  Never know when your neighbour or crazy uncle/aunt with a tank will pull the fence(with the support post with it).

Comment: @crip659 - Well, it isn't *required* for support. I just felt like since I already had very similar-looking posts that were, it would kind of blend in better aesthetically that way.